# Does the pressurized lung augmentation in Starfinder protect a character from the effects of sudden decompression?

Tags: damage, starfinder

According to the Starfinder rules, the pressurized lungs biotech augmentation has the following effect:

> "You can hold your breath for up to 1 hour and are immune to the normal environmental effects of being in a vacuum."

The rules on vacuums are as follows:

> Vacuum
>
> The void of space is effectively empty of matter, and this vacuum is perhaps the greatest danger of outer space. A creature introduced to a vacuum immediately begins to suffocate (see Suffocation and Drowning) and takes 1d6 bludgeoning damage per round (no saving throw). Because a vacuum has no effective temperature, the void of outer space presents no dangers from cold temperatures. A creature retains its body heat for several hours in a vacuum. Sound doesn’t travel in a vacuum.
>
> Decompression occurs when a creature suddenly transitions from a pressurized environment to a vacuum, such as by being flung out of an airlock or being inside a sealed structure that becomes heavily damaged. Such a creature takes 3d6 bludgeoning damage (no saving throw) in addition to any suffocation damage.
>
> Most creatures travel the vacuum of space in a starship.

Do the 3d6 points suffered from sudden decompression (discussed in the second paragraph under Vacuum) count as the "normal environmental effects of being in a vacuum"? Or do normal environmental effects only pertain to the suffoction and 1d6 per round?

---

[Here](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/survival-in-space-unprotected-possible/) is an article about the real science.

It is logical for lungs that hold an hour's worth of air to protect you from suffocation in a vacuum, and they theoretically could stop your lungs from bursting (another danger in a vacuum). I don't see how they would prevent your blood from vaporizing and stopping circulation. Scientifically, even with pressurized lungs, the vacuum should damage/kill you. Granted, it is a fantasy game.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Yes

You present all the information needed. The ability quoted, with relevant text bolded:

> You can hold your breath for up to 1 hour and are **immune to the normal environmental effects of being in a vacuum**.

And, to paraphrase, the "normal environmental effects of being in a vacuum" are:

> [...]
> Decompression occurs when a creature suddenly transitions from a pressurized environment to a vacuum, such as by being flung out of an airlock or being inside a sealed structure that becomes heavily damaged. Such a creature takes 3d6 bludgeoning damage (no saving throw) in addition to any suffocation damage.
> [...]

The section is directly under the Vacuum heading for environmental effects, so it is a *normal* effect of entering (in this case, rapidly) a vacuum environment.

Only things having to do with a vacuum that are *not* in the presented section (perhaps caused by a malicious spell or other phenomenon, such as being too close to a stellar body) would still be able to affect such a character.

Comment: I might have argued the semantics of “being in a vacuum” vice “entering a vacuum,” but you made a good case for non-normal effects not described in the rules, and even gave possible examples. That put put this answer over the top. Accepted.